# WCF and the [DataMember] Attribute

Tags: c#, wcf

I have the following (abbreviated) class that is sent and received to/from the client via WCF:

```
public class Sparetime : ChartConfigurationBase, IChartConfiguration
{
    [DataMember]
    public int SparetimeConfigurationId { get; set; }

    public Single FeederOffRate { get; set; }
}
```

Notice the first property uses the DataMember attribute and the second doesn't. Am I correct that only the first property would get serialized and sent to the client when a WCF call is made?

Comment: "Interface implementation. Not used by the chart" Unrelated, but have you considered explicit interface implementation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you are right, the  [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx) specifies it :

> When applied to the member of a type, specifies that the member is
>   part of a data contract and is serializable by the
>   DataContractSerializer.

You should add [DataContract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx) attribute to your class to make it serializable :

```
[DataContract]
public class Sparetime : ChartConfigurationBase, IChartConfiguration
{
}
```

Note that `FeederOffRate` will be set to its default value (null for reference types).

Comment: You're welcome, if you want to go deeper in DataContract deserialization, you can see the Notes section at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx